# Zxing Compare Result against local Data?

Tags: java, arrays, zxing, barcode-scanner

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Current working method without comparing against Data^

Below is method where Result is compared with Data to see if there is a duplicate(not working)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == 555821282,8882288,888822884,1145698,248635887,4477996) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Yes");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "No");
            Toast.makeText(this, "No: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I get the Integer is too large. I have 500 UPC to put there but I cant even put one. Can I put the numbers in a file somewhere on Android Studio and reference it there? What is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`IntentResut.getContents()` returns a String. To compare two strings in Java, you should use the `String.equals(String)` method. Your `onActivityResult` should look like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        String data = result.getContents();
        if (data != null) {
            if (data.equals("555821282") 
                    || data.equals("8882288")
                    || data.equals("888822884")
                    /* ... rest of the options ... */ ) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Yes");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "No");
                Toast.makeText(this, "No: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            // No data
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Since you have 500 UPCs to compare, you probably don't want to write a 500 line if-statement. Instead I'd recommend putting all the UPCs (as strings) into a List and then your if-statement can check if the list contains the barcode.

```
List<String> knownUpcs = Arrays.asList("555821282", "8882288", "888822884", "1145698", "248635887", "4477996");
...
if (knownUpcs.contains(data)) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Here the list is defined statically, but there is no reason you couldn't create the list by reading the UPCs from a file on disk.